# Setting two variables *always* equal?

Tags: c++

After doing:

```
int a = 2;
int b = a;
a = 4;
```

`b` remains 2, which is very logical and in most of the cases very useful.

Is there any way for `a` and `b` to have always the same value, meaning that when *one* of them changes, the *other* also gets the same value?

For example:

```
//magic I am looking for
a = 2;
// now also b is equal to 2
b = 3;
// now also a is equal to 3
```

**closest I could get (you can ignore this, it may not be leading anywhere):**

```
int a =2;
int *ptr = &a;
int *b = ptr;
a = 9;
cout << *b;
```

and `*b` is 9, changing `*b` into 9 makes also `a == 9`.

**but** `a` and `*b` are not the same data type (int and pointer int), and I can't seem to get it to work within a list.

*Edit: I didn't specify the language cause I wasn't sure in which one this could exist. It looks like C++ has some similar features (references) like the one I am looking for.*

*My only concern is that also references aren't working within an array, like my above solution.*

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different features. Pick the one you use!

Comment: Make them both point at the same location.  Either make both a pointer and alloc memory, or make one a pointer (but then the syntax is different, as you must remeber to derefence the one that's a pointer when you use it)

Comment: I see you have fixed on C++ since you used `cout` stream and `<<` operator. Please remove the C tag. For C++ you can use references as answered by @CoryKramer

Comment: FYI, you are asking how to make `b` an _alias_ of `a`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)

Comment: As long as `a` and `b` refer to different memory addresses, they cannot be linked together the way you want.  They have to refer to the same memory address instead, which means either declaring one of them to be a pointer/reference to the other, or else putting both variables in a `union`.

Comment: Did somebody tear some pages out of your C++ book?

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking about C++, you can use references

```
int a = 2;
int& b = a;

a = 4;  // now b also == 4
```

Otherwise if both are of type `int`, each variable contains its own value at its own memory location, and does not "know" about the other, nor will updating one modify the other.

Comment: C doesa not support references.

Comment: @Olaf I've updated my answer to specify that this is in C++. If the OP states that they are only interested in C I will delete my answer.

Comment: Yes, but as it looks OP wants something impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about C, you can't link two variables together that way.

You can however create multiple *pointers* to that variable.  Then when you dereference any of those pointers you see the results reflected.

```
int a = 1;
int *b = &a;
int *c = &a;

int a = 2;
printf("*b=%d, *c=%d\n", *b, *c);
```

Output:

```
*b=2, *c=2
```